# Cannot get image content from OneNoteAPI

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am trying to display page content of my OneNote's page using Angular Web. A**lthough I can get the other contents, I cannot get images from OneNote page**. Here is the code that I am using for getting page content and the error.

```
public async getOneNoteContent(pageUrl: any) {  
let url = pageUrl+'/?preAuthenticated=true';
let token =  await this.authService.getAccessToken();
let header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);
return(this.http.get(url, {headers:header, responseType: 'text'}));}
```

[image: Error Code]

How can I solve this. Please help me.

Comment: 1. Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.  2. Provide your reference Microsoft graph api document.

Comment: You are getting a 401 Unauthorized. Are you adding preAuthenticated=true to your request?

Comment: Sorry I see it in your url. What  happens if you paste the link directly into a browser?

Comment: Please check if you have Notes.Read.All permission in your scope and if not add it and give a try. Also please share the requestid and timestamp of this failed request.